# Why cant I display images from ACF fields?

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom field ( taxonomy) in which there is a field `featured_image` where under different tests results display different pictures, now that I am trying to get these images with this code

```
  $image = get_field('featured_image');

  if( !empty($image) ): ?>

  <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
  <?php endif;
```

It doesnt return anything, when i `var_dump($image)` it displays NULL

[The field itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qcPS.jpg)

Comment: Is this field attached to a taxonomy term? Where are you trying to output this image? If this is on a taxonomy term, you need to pass the term slug to the `get_field()`. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

Comment: @disinfor Yes this is attached to a taxonomy term, I am trying to display  it under `taxonomy = answer` and `post type = test`

Answer (score 0):

You will need `get_sub_field()` for ACF image types, which returns an array.

```
<?php
    $image = get_sub_field('featured_image');
?>
<img src="<?php echo $image['url'];?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `taxonomy` and `term_id` to the `get_field` to get the information:

```
$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;       

$image = get_field('featured_image', 'answer_' . $term_id );       

if( !empty($image) ): ?>      
     <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
<?php endif;
```

Here's the documentation:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

Comment: Hey ,  why did you put a `answer_`   in this line `$image = get_field('featured_image', 'answer_' . $term_id );  `

Comment: You stated that `answer` was the name of the taxonomy. So you need to pass the taxonomy name AND the term id of the term under answer